# Correct filter expression in libpcap for outgoing packets

Tags: c, libpcap, bpf

I want to sniff only outgoing 'TCP-ACK' packet from my system. Hence I set my filter expression in my `lib-pcap` program as:

```
char filter_exp[] = "src host 172.16.0.1 and tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn | tcp-fin | tcp-rst | tcp-psh) == 0";
```

But it's showing an lib-pcap syntax error at runtime as:

> Couldn't parse filter src host 172.16.0.1 and tcp[tcpflags] and (tcp-syn | tcp-fin | tcp-rst | tcp-psh) == 0: syntax error

Can anybody tell what's wrong here and what would be the correct filter expression for this?

I got the syntax from [here](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) (in the Examples section.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect because `tcp-psh` is not a valid syntax. The correct one is `tcp-push`. So the correct filter expression will be:

```
char filter_exp[] = "src host 172.16.0.1 and tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn | tcp-fin | tcp-rst | tcp-push) == 0";
```